# Writing a stored procedure in db2 10.x version

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw, database-cursor

I am new to db2 and am writing a db2 procedure as follows

```
create procedure ret_mult_rows(in var1 varchar(20),
   out var2 varchar(20),
   out var3 varchar(20))
begin
declare c1 cursor with return to caller for
  select emp_name,emp_city from employee;

open c1;
fetch c1 into var2,var3;
close c1;
end;
```

Basically as an example the employee table may contain 100 rows and I want to return all 100 rows to the calling program (in this case a java program)
However when I execute the stored procedure in stand alone mode using RapidSQL, it is only showing 1 row. What kind of changes are required so that it shows all the 100 rows in the Rapid SQL.
Any kind of pointers/answers will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What platform and version of Db2?  Have you look at the manuals?

There's a difference between an stored procedure output variable and returning a (cursor) result set..

Your code should look something like so...

```
create procedure ret_mult_rows(in var1 varchar(20))
begin
  declare c1 cursor with return to caller for
    select emp_name,emp_city from employee;

  open c1;
end;
```

You want the cursor itself `return to client`, you don't want the stored procedure to `fetch` from it.

**possibly applicable only to Db2 for IBM i**
Also note that while many examples use `C1` as a cursor name, best practice is to have a unique name.  If your client happened to call two stored procs and both used `C1` you'll run into issues..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. version is 10.5.7. I just gave a pseudo code and will make sure to use proper naming convention in the actual code. Thanks for the observation :)

Comment: I think your comment about the cursor name is incorrect. The name is local to the procedure code and is not known to the caller, so it's totally safe to name cursors in all your procedures whichever way you want.

Comment: @mustaccio you may be correct about Db2 LUW...which is what the OP is using...but I've seen using C1 cause problem in Db2 for IBM i.